# Prove for any $a>1$ there exist a natural number, $N$, such that $a^n>n$ for all $n \ge N$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove for any $a>1$ there exist a natural number, $N$, such that $a^n>n$ for all $n \ge N$

My attempt:

By definition, for $N$ to be a natural number $1\le N \le ∞$ for any integer $N$.

By induction, the base case $n=1$ is true because $a^1>1$ which is true.

Now assume that $a^k>k$ is true, then it is also true for $n= k+1$.

Hypothesis

$a^{k+1}>k+1$

Now I am not sure if I am on the right track

Answer (score 5):

Let $x = a-1 > 0$ (by hypothesis). $a^n = (1+x)^n > \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} x^2$ for $n \ge 2$ by the binomial theorem, and the last term is $\ge n$ if $\frac {n-1} {2} x^2 \ge 1$. So if $n \ge 1 + \dfrac{2}{x^2} $ (which also automatically makes $n \ge 2$), you have $a^n > n$.

Comment: This solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x} =\infty,$$ there is an $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$ we will have $$\frac{a^n}{n}>1.$$

Comment: Why is the limit infinity? How would you prove that without being circular?

Comment: Using L'hopital. I wrote $x$ istead of $n$ in order to use L'hopital.

Comment: Oh I see. Nice one.+1

Comment: How does the first part imply the second?

Comment: It goes to infinity, this means it is bigger than for any reel number $M$ after for some $N$. We can choose $M=1$.

Comment: I actually use limit since you tag "real analysis".

Answer (score 0):

More is true:

For any $a > 1$ and $k > 1$
there is a
$n(a, k)$
such that
$n > n(a, k)
\implies a^n > n^k$.

Proof:

$a^n
= e^{n \ln(a)}
\gt \dfrac{(n \ln(a))^m}{m!}
$
for all $m$
(from the power series for
$e^x$).

We want to make
$\dfrac{(n \ln(a))^m}{m!}
\gt n^k
$.
If we choose
$m = k+1$,
this is
$\dfrac{(n \ln(a))^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
\gt n^k
$
or
$n > \dfrac{(k+1)!}{\ln(a)^{k+1}}
$.

By choosing $m$ larger
compared with $k$
we can get
a smaller bound for $n$,
but this is enough.

Comment: This, too, can be proved without calculus, using just elementary algebra (the binomial theorem), as shown in my answer. The general idea is the same - just use the $x^{k+1}$ term in the binomial expansion. Problems like the one asked by the OP should not use much more advanced tools than the problem itself.